# split datasource into multiple mat tables

Tags: angular7

I'm receiving multiple json objects (about current builds in Jenkins) from a backend server, and iterating through this and adding to a datasource. Now, the main problem I get is that I want all builds that are related to each other into same table, and then generate a new table for the next build. Generating the tables dynamically, went easy, but it generates a table for each build, where I'd like the same build to stick in the same loop.

I've tried nesting ngFor loops in the html file, but I end up with the same outcome.

[multiple tables instead of three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXERN.png)

Trying to split the datasource into three datasources ended up breaking the ngFor loop generating the tables.

html file:

```
  <div *ngFor="let data of dataSources[0];">{{data.serviceName}}
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSources" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="jobnumber">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Job Number</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef=""> {{data.jobNumber}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef=""> {{data.serviceName}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
etc
```

ts file receiving from backend:

```
if ( incomingData !== null ) {
        incomingData.service.forEach(element => {
          element.forEach(service => {
            if ( service[7] === 'server') {
              let data= {
                name : service[1],
                duration: service[2],
                timestamp : service[3],
                result : service[4],
                jobNumber : service[6],
                serviceType : service[7],
                serviceName : service[8]
              }
              this.foo.push(data);
            }

          });
        },
        this.dataSources.push(this.foo)
        );
```

The images shows 6 tables. I'd like three, where the name decides in which table the data should be shown. I.E. All Baz in one table and all Bar in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it removing forEach and instead map the backend data:

```
 if ( incomingData !== null ) {
        incomingData.service.map((services) => {
          let service = [];
          services.map((build) => {
            let jenkin = {
              name : build[1],
              duration: build[2],
              timestamp : build[3],
              result : build[4],
              jobNumber : build[6],
              serviceType : build[7],
              serviceName : build[8]
            }
            service.push(jenkin)
        })
        this.dataSources.push(service)
        })
      }
```

and then in the html file:

```
  <div *ngFor="let data of dataSources;">
    <mat-table [dataSource]=data class="mat-elevation-z8">
```